# Node JS & SQL on request per connection?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I can't seem to make multiple requests from one connection to the database. It always tells me that requests can only be made from logged in state.

For example as seen in the code below: the `getCarIdandOwner` part of the function will fire fine. However the `getChargeRate` will not.

I tried combining them like so:

`connection.execSqlBatch(getcarIdandOwner, getChargeRate);`

However that did not work either as it told me that `getChargeRate` was not defined.

Using Visual Studio Community, have NPM: Underscore and Tedious (for sql) installed. Just running it as a console app for now to test.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
    userName: 'user',
    password: 'passs',
    server: 'somewhere.database.windows.net',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        database: 'db-Test',
        useColumnNames: true
var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    // If no error, then good to proceed.  
    console.log("Connected".green);
    toll("******-b77c-40e0-8f26-d44e98bc7264", "be45c903-****-****-b6ba-4b2fefa3d6b0");
}); 

function toll(chipId, locId) {
    var carId = '';
    var userOwner = '';
    var charge = '';
    var userBalance = '';

    getcarIdandOwner = new Request(`SELECT car_id, userOwner FROM Cars WHERE carChipId = '${chipId}'`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    getcarIdandOwner.on('row', function (columns) {
        carId = columns.car_id.value;
        userOwner = columns.userOwner.value;
        console.log('carId: ', carId, ' userOwner: ', userOwner);
    });
    getcarIdandOwner.on('done', function (rowCount, more) {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
        if (rowCount = 1) {
            console.log('Car Rows Returned Ok'.green);
        } else {
            console.log('Fatal Error: More than 1 Car Row Returned'.red);
        };
    });
    connection.execSqlBatch(getcarIdandOwner);

    getChargeRate = new Request(`SELECT Charge FROM locations WHERE location_id = '${locId}'`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    getChargeRate.on('row', function (columns) {
        charge = columns.charge.value;
        console.log('Charging account: ', userOwner, '$', charge);
    });

    connection.execSqlBatch(getChargeRate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some documentation at http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html which states:

> Only one request at a time may be executed on a connection. Once a
>   Request has been initiated (with callProcedure, execSql, or
>   execSqlBatch), another should not be initiated until the Request's
>   completion callback is called.

So your code should be someting like this:

```
function toll(chipId, locId) {
    var carId = '';
    var userOwner = '';
    var charge = '';
    var userBalance = '';

    getcarIdandOwner = new Request(`SELECT car_id, userOwner FROM Cars WHERE carChipId = '${chipId}'`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            getChargeRate = new Request(`SELECT Charge FROM locations WHERE location_id = '${locId}'`, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
            getChargeRate.on('row', function (columns) {
                charge = columns.charge.value;
                console.log('Charging account: ', userOwner, '$', charge);
            });
            connection.execSql(getChargeRate);
        }
    });

    getcarIdandOwner.on('row', function (columns) {
        carId = columns.car_id.value;
        userOwner = columns.userOwner.value;
        console.log('carId: ', carId, ' userOwner: ', userOwner);
    });
    getcarIdandOwner.on('done', function (rowCount, more) {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
        if (rowCount = 1) {
            console.log('Car Rows Returned Ok'.green);
        } else {
            console.log('Fatal Error: More than 1 Car Row Returned'.red);
        };
    });
    connection.execSqlBatch(getcarIdandOwner);

}
```

Comment: Would the .on('done' be the completion Callback? Or is it just when the request returns (ideally) without an error in the `if else`

Comment: It should be in the Request's completion callback: `new Request('sql', function (err, rowCount) {//here...}`. BTW, you can also move the code in the `Event: done` section to this callback function.

Comment: Hey I have a few questions about some code, is there anyway I could contact you directly since you seem knowledgeable

Comment: Hi, you'd better post new questions on Stackoverflow where has a massive community of developers, who may be able to answer your question or give suggestions.